LAnn$_R(a)$ denotes the kernel of some ring homomorphism.
Let LAnn$_R(a)$ denote the collection of all left annihilators for arbitrary element $a\in R$. I'm curious to show that this subset LAnn$_R(a)\subset R$ denotes an ideal specifically by finding a ring homomorphism on $R$ with LAnn$_R(a)$ as its kernel. (Note: The canonical homomorphism is not a good choice since this would require the assumption that $R/$LAnn$_R(a)$ is a ring.)
My motivation in asking this question is entirely out of interest for developing my familiarity with ring theory. If anybody has any proposals, or would be willing to provide hints, that would be greatly appreciated!

Efforts. I include this part for the sake of demonstrating that a reasonable amount of thought has been put into the question on my end.

The first post I would come across was this. Restating the claim in terms which'll be used on my (this) post: Given ring homomorphism $f:R\to R$, then LAnn$_R(A)$ is just the kernel of group action $a\cdot b=f(a)b$ where $b$ is restricted to $\in A$ (i.e. the collection of all $a\in R$ with permutation representation which maps $b\mapsto0$ for all $b\in A$). Not too sure where to go from here...doesn't seem too greatly enlightening for the construction of such a homomorphism.

Looking into some "candidate homomorphisms", there's the obvious idea that $f(x)=xa$ might work ($a\in A$). And while this is a good choice when looking for an additive group homomorphism with kernel LAnn$_R(A)$, it unfortunately does not give us a well-defined ring homomorphism unless $A\subset R$ is an ideal (or if $A\subset Z(R)$ where all elements $\in A$ are idempotent).

Another candidate would be $f(x)=a^{-1}xa$, and this would be a great choice if it weren't for the fact that $a\in R$ need not be a unit (since it may have zero divisors).

I struggle to think of other candidates...so consider these two traits that will be necessary for any candidate: (i) Given $x,y\in R$, then $xa=0$ and $ya=0$ must imply $(xy)a=(yx)a=0$; (ii) Any element $r\in R$ will be in the kernel of our homomorphism if and only if $ra=0$ (which holds if and only if...? In other terms, what are some alternative ways to view this condition?).



The problem is that a kernel of a ring homomorphism has to be a two-sided ideal even for non-commutative rings, so if the left annihilator is not 2-sided, then such ring cannot exist.

@RHspqr I see...so then I guess my second bullet point gives the ring homomorphism I'd be looking for (to the extent for which I'm searching with respect to what is true), yes?

in a sense yes, but like I said such construction does not work in general as there is some ideal of left annihilators that cannot serve as a kernel simply because they are not two-sided ideals

What you can say is:
The left annihilator of any nonempty subset of $R$ is a left ideal.
The left annihilator of a left ideal is a two-sided ideal.
$Lann(a)$ is precisely the kernel of the $R$ module homomorphism $_RR\to_RR$ given by $r\mapsto ra$.
These three things are often left as exercises, and you probably will not have any issue proving them.
